# 小さな vs 小さい/大きな vs 大きい

Tags: meaning

Is there any difference in meaning between 小さな and 小さい / 大きな and 大きい? I know that they have different syntactical rules, but semantically is there any difference? I was once told that 大きな was more appropriate for non-physical things, e.g. 大きな声.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Shogakukan's *Ruigo Reikai Thesaurus Dictionary* has this to say about differences in meaning and usage:

> 「大きい」は、「夢が大きい」「大きく夢みる」のように述語として、また 連用修飾語としても使うが、「大きな」は「大きな…(名詞)」という言い方でしか使わない。
>     *Ōkii* is used as both predicate and as a continuative modifier as in *yume ga ōkii*, *ōkiku yume miru*, but *ōkina* is only used in  the format of *ōkina*...(noun).
>
> 物事の程度や、関わる範囲などが大であるという意で名詞を修飾する場合、その名詞が「問題」「影響」など抽象名詞のときは、「大きな」を用いることが多い。
>     When modifying a noun to mean that a thing's degree or relevant scope is large, *ōkina* is used more often when the noun is abstract, such as a "problem" or "effect".

There's also a table indicating different valid and invalid constructions, which I've clumsily recreated below.  The - indicates an invalid use, while the △ indicates an acceptable but less-common use.

> ～声 | 声が～ | ～問題に発展する | ～影響がある | ～拍手で迎えられる
>   大きい     〇 |    〇        |               △            |           △         |                〇
>   大きな     〇 |    －     |               〇           |           〇         |                〇

As shown above, both 大きい声 and 大きな声 would be equally valid.  The person who told you that 大きな should be used more for non-physical things might have used the wrong word; given the description above, the distinction appears to be *abstract* vs. *concrete*, rather than *physical* vs. *non-physical*.

Grammatically, 小さい and 小さな have the same usage constraints as 大きい and 大きな.  The thesaurus does not, however, mention any differences in *abstract* vs. *concrete* between 小さい and 小さな.